# Base64 Decoding of UTF 8 character and printing it

Tags: scala, utf-8, base64

I have UTF8 character which are encoded in Base64. I am decoding it and trying to print it.But its only priting its hex value but not the UTF-8 String.

Things I tried

1: I have verified the Character is online decoder which tell me that the string I get is of right format:
https://www.base64decode.org/

2: System.getProperty("file.encoding") is also UTF8

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")

    val sd = Base64.getDecoder.decode("7IiY7KeE7IiY7KeE7IiY7KeE7IiY7KeE7IiY7KeE7IiY7KeE7IiY7KeE7IiY7KeE7IiY")
    println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"))
    println(sd.toString())

    val sb = new StringBuffer

    var i:Int=0

    while(i<sd.length){
      sb.append("%02X".format(sd(i) & 0xff))

      i=i+1

    }
    println(sb)

  }
```

What am I missing in this one ?
Actruall string required is as below:

수진수진수진수진수진수진수진수진수

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply using `new String(sd, "UTF-8")`, which will return your characters. Worked on my machine, result: `수진수진수진수진수진수진수진수진수`

Answer (score 0):

The `X` in `"%02X".format(sd(i) & 0xff)` specifies upper case hexadecimal. Try `%s` to get the UTF-8 string.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the answer. I tried with sb.append("%s".format(sd(i) & 0xff)) Still I am not getting required UTF8 messsage

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: Its  printing  each characters Ascii value 236136152236167132236136152236167132236136152236167132236136152236167132236136152236167132236136152236167132236136152236167132236136152236167132236136152

Comment: Try `%ls` for "wide"  characters.